How to get the start index of a selected text within a multiline text of a div?
Assume I have an editable div which contains these lines:

How to retrieve the position of 'w' in the text ?
I can't use:
window.getSelection().anchorOffset;

Because this gets the position in the line, but not in text, that is 0 instead of 5.
I prefer not to use:
element.innerText.indexOf(selectedText);

Because it may retrieve similar texts.

Your anchor offset should be 6.



Index
Character





0
H



1
e



2
l



3
l



4
o



5
\n



6
w
<- Here


7
o



8
r



9
l



10
d






const el = document.querySelector('#test');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

el.focus();
selectText(el, 'w');
btn.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click')); // 6

function getPos(event) {
  const anchor = getSelectionIndices(window.getSelection());
  console.log(anchor.start); // Display only the first index...
}

function selectText(el, text) {
  const content = el.textContent;
  const startIndex = content.indexOf(text);
  if (startIndex === -1) return;
  const endIndex = startIndex + text.length;
  selectTextRange(el, startIndex, endIndex);
}

function selectTextRange(el, startIndex, endIndex) {
  const textNode = el.firstChild;
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(textNode, startIndex);
  range.setEnd(textNode, endIndex);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}

function getSelectionIndices(selection) {
  const { anchorOffset, focusOffset } = selection;
  return {
    start: Math.min(anchorOffset, focusOffset),
    end: Math.max(focusOffset, anchorOffset)
  };
}
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 4rem !important; }
<div id="test" style="white-space:pre;" contenteditable>Hello
world</div>
<br>
<button id="btn" onClick="getPos(event)">Get Selection</button>




Thank you for your answer and your time.
There is still a problem while editing the text.
.anchorOffset works only on originally attached text and not on a new text inserted.
As I said .anchorOffset will return 0 for the 'w' in this case.
I will try to build a function that counts the lines till the selected text.

this code has a huge bug! when you want to select a character, you first need to place the cursor between two chars (like between \nw or wo) and then start selecting (using mouse cursor or keyboard). this code only shows the offset of the original cursor (which can be between w and o) which can be also 7 if you start selecting between w and o and coming back a character.

@MHSarmadi I added a getSelectionIndices utility to extract the start and end indices from a selection.

@MHSarmadi : I replaced my answer by a new version.

Here is a 'prototype' function to get the offset. This is a new version of my original answer.
This function sums up the new lines chars('\n') and the text lengths of the lines till the selection start.
In fact, the lines within editable DIV are interior elements (like P or DIV etc.) ,  as in the image:

The interior structure varies according to the sites , like LinkedIn Facebook etc.
I recommend to see explanation for some of the terms on Laimonas answer.
The function isn't fit to Twitter , because there is need to add a condition for first-grand-grand-child.
So this function can be improved , but it is a good help to get the offset, which I didn't find yet in Javascript.
Example for use to get the offset:
var offset = GetOffset(event);

To get the focus offset:
var focusOffset = GetOffset(event,"focus");



// Get the offset according the user view , that is , the offset from the beginning of the text
function GetOffset(event, node_type = null) {
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    var anchorOffset = GetRealOffset(event, "anchor");
    var focusOffset = GetRealOffset(event, "focus");
    if (!node_type) 
        return (anchorOffset < focusOffset) ? anchorOffset : focusOffset
    else
        return GetRealOffset(event, node_type);
    //Get the real offset of the anchor/focus according to 'npdetype'
    function GetRealOffset(event, nodetype) {
        const node = (nodetype == "anchor") ? selection.anchorNode : selection.focusNode;
        let offset = 0;
        let currentNode = node;
        let nodeOffset = (nodetype == "anchor") ? selection.anchorOffset : 
            (currentNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) ? selection.focusOffset : 0; // Initializing nodeOffset to 0 , if ther was no selection
        while (currentNode && currentNode !== event.target) {  // event.target is the element on which we work now
            var lastNode = null;
            while (currentNode) { // Summing the the text length of the nodes plus the new line chars repressented by the node itself.
                lastNode = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.previousSibling;
                if (currentNode) {
                    if (currentNode !== event.target.firstChild && currentNode !== event.target && currentNode.nodeName !== 'SPAN')
                        offset++;
                    if (currentNode.children && currentNode.children.length && currentNode.children[0].nodeName === 'BR')  
                        offset++;
                    if (currentNode.previousSibling && currentNode.previousSibling.nodeName === 'P') // P element has a new line also in its end.
                        offset++;
                    offset += currentNode.textContent.length;
                }
            }
            currentNode = lastNode.parentNode; // Upleveling to the parent of the anchor/focus node (i.e. from text node to the element node.)
            if (currentNode !== event.target.firstChild && currentNode !== event.target && currentNode.nodeName !== 'SPAN')
                offset += 1;  // Adds the newline char ('\n')
            if (currentNode.previousSibling && currentNode.previousSibling.nodeName === 'P')
                offset++;
        }
        offset += nodeOffset;
        return offset;
    }
}

This solution isn't fit to Mozilla Firefox where you can select multiple texts.
Pay attention :
This function returns the offset in the text that include also unvisible new lines chars('\n'). So, if you press Enter between 'hello' and 'world' then delete it, the results will be chanched.


var element = document.getElementById("target");
var button = document.getElementById("but");
function MyFunction(){
    console.log("The offset is : " +GetOffset(target) );
}function GetOffset(targetElement, node_type = null) {
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    var anchorOffset = GetRealOffset(targetElement, "anchor");
    var focusOffset = GetRealOffset(targetElement, "focus");
    if (!node_type) 
        return (anchorOffset < focusOffset) ? anchorOffset : focusOffset
    else
        return GetRealOffset(targetElement, node_type);
    //Get the real offset of the anchor/focus according to 'npdetype'
    function GetRealOffset(targetElement, nodetype) {
        const node = (nodetype == "anchor") ? selection.anchorNode : selection.focusNode;
        let offset = 0;
        let currentNode = node;
        let nodeOffset = (nodetype == "anchor") ? selection.anchorOffset : 
            (currentNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) ? selection.focusOffset : 0; // Initializing nodeOffset to 0 , if ther was no selection
        while (currentNode && currentNode !== targetElement) {  // targetElement.target is the element on which we work now
            var lastNode = null;
            while (currentNode) { // Summing the the text length of the nodes plus the new line chars repressented by the node itself.
                lastNode = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.previousSibling;
                if (currentNode) {
                    if (currentNode !== targetElement.firstChild && currentNode !== targetElement && currentNode.nodeName !== 'SPAN')
                        offset++;
                    if (currentNode.children && currentNode.children.length && currentNode.children[0].nodeName === 'BR')  
                        offset++;
                    if (currentNode.previousSibling && currentNode.previousSibling.nodeName === 'P') // P element has a new line also in its end.
                        offset++;
                    offset += currentNode.textContent.length;
                }
            }
            currentNode = lastNode.parentNode; // Upleveling to the parent of the anchor/focus node (i.e. from text node to the element node.)
            if (currentNode !== targetElement.firstChild /*&& currentNode.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE */&& currentNode !== targetElement && currentNode.nodeName !== 'SPAN')
                offset += 1;  // Adds the newline char ('\n')
            if (currentNode.previousSibling && currentNode.previousSibling.nodeName === 'P')
                offset++;
        }
        offset += nodeOffset;
        return offset;
    }
}
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 4rem !important; }
<p>Select some text from the text below 
Or type new text and select some of it
then press the button.</p>
<button id="but" style="width:80px;height:20px;"onclick="MyFunction()">Get offset</button>
</div>

<div id="target" style='border:1px solid;' contenteditable="true">Hello<div>World</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>



